# Enabling layout measuring tool / ruler in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, esri-production-mapping

According to ArcMap help, I'm supposed to be able to open the Measure Layout Tool in the Production Cartography toolbar:

Customize > Toolbars > Production Cartography.

described here:

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/production-mapping/the-measure-layout-tool.htm

However, my Arc version (10.4) does not have this toolbar. I simply can't find a layout measure tool, which is completely ridiculous. The measure tool that I can find only works for map elements, but not for layout elements such as text boxes, data frames, etc.

If you can't measure layout elements how do you create decently laid out maps?

I'm sure I'm missing some simple step or connection. . . though the difficulty I am facing while looking for this information (google searches, tutorial videos, etc.) plus the unavailability of this tool (or any measure / ruler tool in cartographic toolsets) has driven me to ask for advice.

Comment: You need to contact ESRI support for pricing of the Production Mapping Extension http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/what-is-production-mapping.htm

Comment: It's ridiculous to have to purchase an entire extension for such a basic tool.

Comment: The Tool has more than just the measuring tool.

Comment: Yes of course, it's just surprising that such a basic tool is only available as an advanced cartographic extension.

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth - I can't seem to find the production cartography toolbar in ArcMap 10.3 either - perhaps it's a licence issue.

One tip that may help you - if you want to specify the size of layout elements you can right-click on the element and select Properties>Size and Position.
In this tab you can precisely specify the width and height of the frame.

*Edited to add*: another tip for precise frame placement is to use the arrow keys.   The default 'nudge' size is rather large; but if you press shift-arrow instead then you can get much more precise element placing.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but of course it doesn't measure the gaps between elements... I could perhaps create polygons to fill those gaps and adjust their sizes but all i want is a ruler, damn it!! :)                          I discovered a Production Mapping extension https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/production-mapping/what-is-production-mapping.htm which features the kind of ruler I'm looking for but you have to pay for it and  it seems foolish to not include this very ordinary feature in the ordinary layout tools...

Comment: You can also specify positions in that tab.  It may take a bit of work with calculating the offsets by hand - but it will be possible.  Also I've edited my reply to add a further tip on using shift-arrow for precise element placing.